# How to find and use methods for DotNetRestore, DotNetBuild etc in Nuke.Build 6.2.1

Tags: c#, nuke-build

I'm trying to learn how to use Nuke.build but I'm having trouble right from the start.
I've followed the documentation and added a nuke project to my solution by typing `nuke` and following the prompts.

I now have three empty targets in Build.cs:

```
Target Clean => _ => _
        .Before(Restore)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
        });

    Target Restore => _ => _
        .Executes(() =>
        {
        });

    Target Compile => _ => _
        .DependsOn(Restore)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
        });
```

My problem is that I can't find how to actually perform a clean, restore or compile.
The closest thing I've found to explicit instructions is this page from the docs: https://nuke.build/docs/common/cli-tools/

But I can't find any of the methods being referred to.
I'm obviously missing a using statement that points to a bunch of extension methods. But I can't find where they are.
Where are these methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it myself. I needed to add the following using statement:

```
using static Nuke.Common.Tools.DotNet.DotNetTasks;
```